# SqlException when upgrading linq2sql app from SQL Server 2005 to 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I'm upgrading a web app from SQL Server 2005 to 2008.

For a query like:

```
(from e in context.Orders
group e by e.OrderDate.Value.Date.AddDays(-e.OrderDate.Value.Date.Day + 1) into g
orderby g.Count() descending
select new
{
Value = g.Count(),
Date = g.Key
}).FirstOrDefault().Dump();
```

I'm now getting "SqlException: The datepart millisecond is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date."

The page:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/6b00d5a4-8b43-402a-bcf7-b8516b6ffdf5/

...describes the problem further but has no solution.

With 2005 provider linq2sql produces:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int SET @p0 = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (1) [t2].[value2] AS [Value], [t2].[value3] AS [Date]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], COUNT(*) AS [value2], [t1].[value] AS [value3]
    FROM (
        SELECT DATEADD(ms, (CONVERT(BigInt,(CONVERT(Float,(-DATEPART(Day, DATEADD(HOUR, -DATEPART(HOUR, [t0].[OrderDate]), DATEADD(MINUTE, -DATEPART(MINUTE, [t0].

[OrderDate]), DATEADD(SECOND, -DATEPART(SECOND, [t0].[OrderDate]), DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -DATEPART(MILLISECOND, [t0].[OrderDate]), [t0].[OrderDate])))))) + @p0)) * 

86400000)) % 86400000, DATEADD(day, (CONVERT(BigInt,(CONVERT(Float,(-DATEPART(Day, DATEADD(HOUR, -DATEPART(HOUR, [t0].[OrderDate]), DATEADD(MINUTE, -DATEPART

(MINUTE, [t0].[OrderDate]), DATEADD(SECOND, -DATEPART(SECOND, [t0].[OrderDate]), DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -DATEPART(MILLISECOND, [t0].[OrderDate]), [t0].

[OrderDate])))))) + @p0)) * 86400000)) / 86400000, DATEADD(HOUR, -DATEPART(HOUR, [t0].[OrderDate]), DATEADD(MINUTE, -DATEPART(MINUTE, [t0].[OrderDate]), DATEADD

(SECOND, -DATEPART(SECOND, [t0].[OrderDate]), DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -DATEPART(MILLISECOND, [t0].[OrderDate]), [t0].[OrderDate])))))) AS [value]
        FROM [Orders] AS [t0]
        ) AS [t1]
    GROUP BY [t1].[value]
    ) AS [t2]
ORDER BY [t2].[value] DESC
```

And on 2008:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (1) [t2].[value2] AS [Value], [t2].[value3] AS [Date]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], COUNT(*) AS [value2], [t1].[value] AS [value3]
    FROM (
        SELECT DATEADD(ms, (CONVERT(BigInt,(CONVERT(Float,(-DATEPART(Day, CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[OrderDate]))) + @p0)) * 86400000)) % 86400000, DATEADD(day, (CONVERT

(BigInt,(CONVERT(Float,(-DATEPART(Day, CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[OrderDate]))) + @p0)) * 86400000)) / 86400000, CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[OrderDate]))) AS [value]
        FROM [Orders] AS [t0]
        ) AS [t1]
    GROUP BY [t1].[value]
    ) AS [t2]
ORDER BY [t2].[value] DESC
```

Comment: I take it you cannot upgrade to .Net 4.0 where microsoft have marked this bug as fixed?

Comment: I have upgraded to 4.0 and the problem is still there!

Answer (score 0):

I found one workaround:

```
(from e in context.Orders
group e by new DateTime(e.OrderDate.Value.Year, e.OrderDate.Value.Month, 1) into g
orderby g.Count() descending
select new
{
    Value = g.Count(),
    Date = g.Key
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

But still interested in learning more about this problem.

I tried to change compatability more to Mysql Server 2008 but that didn't help the original query.